# Simple Probability of Playing Cards

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

An ordinary deck of playing cards has four suits: hearts, spades, diamonds, and clubs. Suppose
you have a reduced deck of eight playing cards, consisting of four aces and four kings. I draw
two cards from the deck and look at them without showing you. I then tell you that at least one of
my two cards is an ace. If you use Bayes’ rule, what probability should you now assign to the
claim that both of the cards I drew are aces? Suppose I told you that one of my cards was the ace
of hearts. If you use Bayes’ rule, what is the probability that both of the cards I drew are aces?

Comment: I assume we are drawing without replacement. Our probability is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$ where $B$ is the event at least one Ace, and $A$ is the event two Aces.  The probability of at least one Ace is $1$ minus the probability of $2$ Kings. The probability of two Kings is $\binom{4}{2}/\binom{8}{2}$. The rest is yours to do.

Comment: If it is so simple, why do you don´t have an idea ?